# Possible to see dead proccesses?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, history

In `man ps`, it clearly states the different states a process can have on Linux.

```
D    Uninterruptible sleep (usually IO)
R    Running or runnable (on run queue)
S    Interruptible sleep (waiting for an event to complete)
T    Stopped, either by a job control signal or because it is being traced.
W    paging (not valid since the 2.6.xx kernel)
X    dead (should never be seen)
Z    Defunct ("zombie") process, terminated but not reaped by its parent.
```

Even tho `X` is a process state, it should never be seen. But is that correct? Is there a theoretical way to see that as a state on a process? Or is it completely 100% impossible?

Comment: The use of _should_ and the fact that it's in the man page imply that it is actually possible to see it. I have no idea how or when though.

Answer (score 7):

I took a little dive into the Linux kernel, without knowledge about how it works in its inner core, or any big C knowledge. So please be nice with this theory :)

The `DEAD` state is defined https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/fs/proc/array.c#L141 and is used at https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/fs/exec.c#L974 to give a return status only. So the only way it can ever be seen is if you check the process state before around https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/fs/exec.c#L986 (or later on wherever this function gets called from..).

If you try to kill a dead process it will be taken care of and ignored at https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/kernel/signal.c#L1363

So in theory... I think the answer is yes. X as a state can be seen in theory, but probably have never been in real life..

Please correct me if/where I'm wrong.. I am not sure about this at all..

Comment: I can see it with `until sleep 0.4 & perl -e '$p = shift; while (1) {open A, "</proc/$p/stat" or last; $_=<A>; print}' $! | grep X; do :; done`

Comment: Here is what the process (output of /proc/.../stat) looks like; `4603 (sleep) X 0 -1 -1 0 -1 4202508 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 20 0 0 0 175042279 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 18446744071579306375 0 0 17 0 0 0 0 0 0`.. Question answered. The X is possible! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's evidence of one that we just ran into on a live system:

```
$ sudo ps axf -O wchan
31103 -      R ?        00:00:00 /bin/bash /usr/local/bin/monitorcron taskA
31104 exit   X ?        00:00:00  \_ [su]
```

Comment: Do you remember if the process was gone by the next time you ran `ps`?